# Group rows in a collection by specified columns to build a 3d structure

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections, grouping

I need to group data from a 2d Laravel query result to form a 3d structure.

In Laravel, my data from `->get()->toArray()` result is:

```
[
    ['ts' => 1234, 'a' => 3, 'b' => 2],
    ['ts' => 1244, 'a' => 2, 'b' => 6],
    ['ts' => 1254, 'a' => 8, 'b' => 3],
]
```

Is there any way that I am able to transform the data to as such:

```
[
    ['column' => 'a', 'values' => [[1234, 3], [1244, 2], [1254, 8]],
    ['column' => 'b', 'values' => [[1234, 2], [1244, 6], [1254, 3]],
]
```

I just wish to know if there's any best / efficient way to render the transformation as described above. **Avoid re looping** again as data is already available, it can be thought as a data formatting question. Also, I **do not wish to use additional array** if possible.

Things that I've already looked includes `->get()->map(function())`, however this is sequential and I am not able to get `values` in 2D array as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to map over your items and return the `ts` value, as well as the value for each column, respectively:

```php
$items = Model::all();

$result = [
    [
        'column' => 'a',
        'values' => $items->map(function ($item) {
            return [$item->ts, $item->a];
        })
    ],
    [
        'column' => 'b',
        'values' => $items->map(function ($item) {
            return [$item->ts, $item->b];
        })
    ],
];
```

---

If you want to combine the logic for both columns, create a collection of column names, and map over those:

```php
$items = Model::all();

$result = collect(['a', 'b'])->map(function ($column) use ($items) {
    $values = $items->map(function ($item) use ($column) {
        return [$item->ts, $item->{$column}];
    });

    return compact('column', 'values');
});
```

Comment: Joseph, thanks for your quick inputs, it's indeed working with the outer map to `column`, then inner map to each of the column, that's wonderful. I learnt something, especially the syntax `$item->{$column}`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of traversing all row n times to isolate n column-grouped data sets, use Laravel's `reduce()` method (or PHP's `array_reduce()` function if your data is already converted to an array).  Pushing references into the result array will avoid the need to re-index the first level keys after population.

Code: ([PHPize Demo](https://phpize.online/s/A4))

```
var_export(
    $yourCollection->reduce(
        function ($result, $row) {
            static $ref;
            foreach (['a', 'b'] as $group) {
                if (!isset($ref[$group])) {
                    $ref[$group] = ['column' => $group, 'values' => [[$row['ts'], $row[$group]]]];
                    $result[] =& $ref[$group];
                } else {
                    $ref[$group]['values'][] = [$row['ts'], $row[$group]];
                }
            }
            return $result;
        }
    )
);
```